# Google charts (web) how to add a linear 45 degree line

Tags: php, web, charts, google-visualization

I got scatter chart which is perfectly fine and I can add trend-lines  but I can't find a way just to add a 45 degree line that goes from (0,0) to (1,1) example image below:
[image]

IS there any way to add a line like that to a google chart through it's web API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a [ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) with two series -- scatter and line

just need data for both, use `null` where the rows do not coincide

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'X', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Y', type: 'number'},
        {label: 'Line', type: 'number'},
      ],
      rows: [
        {c:[{v: 3}, {v: 3.5}, null]},
        {c:[{v: 4}, {v: 5.5}, null]},
        {c:[{v: 4}, {v: 5}, null]},
        {c:[{v: 6.5}, {v: 7}, null]},
        {c:[{v: 8}, {v: 12}, null]},
        {c:[{v: 11}, {v: 14}, null]},
        // add line
        {c:[{v: 0}, null, {v: 0}]},
        {c:[{v: 20}, null, {v: 20}]},
      ]
    });

    var options = {
      legend: 'none',
      hAxis: {
        ticks: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
      },
      height: 400,
      series: {
        // line
        1: {
          type: 'line',
          visibleInLegend: false
        },
      },
      seriesType: 'scatter',
      vAxis: {
        ticks: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20]
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Spot on, that's exactly what I wanted. Thank you very much :)